Password refused when trying to SSH as sudo user
I'm sure this question has been asked a million times already. I have spent endless hours Googling and everything I have tried isn't helping.
I have  Debian VM in Azure. I can only connect to the device by console session.
I can run elevated commands as my sudo user so I know my credentials are correct.
However when I try to SSH to it, it responds with "Access Denied".
I have checked my SSH config and it now looks like this:
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.d/%k
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes

I have reset the password and I have added a SSH public key via the Azure portal.
I have checked for logs but it doesn't look like they are turned on.
The firewall doesn't appear to be installed as ufw commands are not recognised.
Is there anything else I could try.
This is the full verbose output
C:\Users\myadmin>ssh -vvv myroot@172.20.2.21
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 172.20.2.21 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.20.2.21 [172.20.2.21] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 172.20.2.21:22 as 'myroot'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.20.2.21
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:wZCiZzvvxoaaGlY5arJwIDroDk1iiw5fv0hnPtRbeLU
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.20.2.21
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myadmin/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host '172.20.2.21' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss (0000000000000000)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myadmin/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
myroot@172.20.2.21's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory


What do the client logs say? ssh -vvv ...

"The firewall doesn't appear to be installed as ufw commands are not recognised" – Non sequitur. ufw is just one of possible "front ends".

myroot@172.20.2.21's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory

Does this mean its looking for a key file as well as a password?

Please update your question and also post sshd_config (server's config).

sshd_config is empty. Added ful verbose output to my original question.

Yeah its empty
myroot@myvm:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d$ ls
myroot@myvm:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d$ ls -lhrt
total 0
myroot@myvm:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d$

Okay just to be clear: you're trying to list contents of the sshd_config.d folder. Is there no sshd_config file?

This really does look like a client-side issue - what does "console session" mean here exactly? Are you using cmd.exe or PowerShell - or something else? OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1 seems rather old (my Win10 laptop has 8.1p1) - what is your Windows version?

@AndroidX the full sshd_config file is pasted into the bode of my original question.

@steeldriver the console session is the Azure console proved in the Azure portal. I have done my debug tests from a command prompt in Windows 11, I have tried via PuTTy and also nRemoteNG.

@Beckyboo You've pasted the ssh_config (client-side configuration file) in the OP, not sshd_config (server-side configuration file). In cases like this it's necessary to check both configs and the server's logs as well to pinpoint the problem. Anyway what's happening here is that your client first tries to connect via public auth method but it doesn't find any key, then proceeds to the password method. The read_passphrase part means that it tries to display an interactive question but for whatever reason fails to do so.

I hope that I have correctly understood your issue - that you want to run ssh as root or via sudo. (All the talk of config files has confused me.)
By design and by default, ssh does not support use by root, for security reasons.
Run man ssh and search for Authentication for an explanation; or PermitRootLogin for a work-around. You may find more readable help by searching for some variation of "Linux ssh root"

"By design and by default, ssh does not support use by root, for security reasons." - no! It quite happily accepts root logins with certificates, and can trivially be configured to accept a password for the root account. Just make sure your root account isn't disabled (and that's nothing to do with ssh)
